# pfsense temporarly failed to resolve hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense

Suddenly I was unable to reach the outside world.

- I pinged one IP on internet, it worked
- I tried to resolve a hostname with the dhpd configured server, i.e. netgate/pfsense, timeout
- I tried to resolve a hostname with the dns resolver configured in
  netgate/pfsense, i.e. 8.8.8.8, it worked

So I incriminate netgate/pfsense.

- What brick of the network could it be ?
- What would be the step to troubleshoot deeper ?

3 minutes later, everything was fine again

Comment: By default pfsense comes with some logging. Go read them. There's no way we can tell, as you include zero information about your configuration or other relevant settings.